# Weblogic JNDI lookup - object transferred or remote invocation

Tags: weblogic, jndi, rmi

I have created a weblogic JMS connection factory and tried to access that from other weblogic server in other machine by using JNDI lookup. so when we do JNDI lookup does the Complete Connection Factory object is transferred to the client side or only the reference to that object is given to that client.

Answer (score 0):

Well you ought to know, it's your factory.

- If it is an exported remote object, a remote reference is transferred, otherwise
- If it is `Serializable`, it is transferred bodily, otherwise
- a `NotSerializableException` is thrown.